Collecting Logs from Cassandra cluster
I have 4 cassandra nodes running on 4 diffrent VMs in docker containers. What's good tool/way to collect logs (optional + metrics ) and look at them through a web ui.
I tried cassandra_explorer https://github.com/criteo/cassandra_exporter/tree/master
but it only collects metrics.

It looks like others are trying to do the same. Here is a guy who did it with logstash unput plugin and the following config. I haven't tried it myself.
Here is a link to the conversation.
file: simple - out.conf
input {
jdbc {
# cassandra jdbc connection string to our database, BTS
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:cql://localhost:173.39.231.46/BTS"
# The user we wish to execute our statement as
jdbc_user => "cassandra"
# The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/cql-3.2.1-1201.jdbc41.jar"
# The name of the driver class
for cqlsh
jdbc_driver_class => "org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver"
# our query
statement => "cqlsh --cqlversion 3.2.1 173.39.231.46 1-u pcia_rw -p hyT%sD3z1KAq25eY -k ks_amer_pda"
}
}
output {
stdout {
codec => json_lines
}
}


SOLVED:I found a way to do it using logstash pipeline
and outputing the containers logs instead of the cassandra log file.
Here's the pipeline configuration.
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/lib/docker/containers/containername/containername-json.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}

filter {
    # You can add filter plugins here to process logs before sending to Elasticsearch.
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://elastic-adress:9200"]
        index => "cassandra-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

